# Can someone explain the flow of control of this program?

Tags: java

This is an example program in my AP Computer Science course, and I can't understand the flow of control of it.

```
public static void mystery( int n )
{
   System.out.println( "mystery called with n = " + n );

   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      System.out.println( "n is zero so no more recursive calls!" );
      return;
   }

   mystery( n - 1 );

   System.out.println( "We did it again with n = " + n );
}

public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
   mystery( 5 );
}
```

It outputs this:

```
mystery called with n = 5
mystery called with n = 4
mystery called with n = 3
mystery called with n = 2
mystery called with n = 1
mystery called with n = 0
n is zero so no more recursive calls!
We did it again with n = 1
We did it again with n = 2
We did it again with n = 3
We did it again with n = 4
We did it again with n = 5
```

So far, I understand the recursive method and how it recalls itself via:

```
mystery( n - 1 );
```

However, I don't see how it can output those five statements after:

```
n is zero so no more recursive calls!
```

Logically, it seems like it would only state:

```
We did it again with n = 0
```

Can anyone help a student out and explain to me how it output what it did?

Comment: For examples sake replace mystery( n - 1 ); with mystery( n-- ); and see how it doesn't do it again.

Comment: It returns before the print when n == 0, thus it will not print anything when n == 0. Previous operations were the recursive calls, that are now finished when n == 0 since it doesn't call itself recursively when n==0, so execution will continue in the code to the printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 'n is zero so no more recursive calls!' the method continues (the state is put on the stack and then loaded after the call to method(n-1) finishes.

Answer (score 4):

When a function finishes, the function that called it has the opportunity to complete and execute more code.

Here is an illustration of how this recursion happens.
Each level of recursion is indicated by an increase in indentation.

```
mystery(5):
    "mystery called with n = 5"
    mystery(4):
        "mystery called with n = 4"
        mystery(3):
            "mystery called with n = 3"
            mystery(2):
                "mystery called with n = 2"
                mystery(1):
                    "mystery called with n = 1"
                    mystery(0):
                        "mystery called with n = 0"
                        "n is zero so no more recursive calls!"
                        mystery(0) returns
                    "We did it again with n = 1"
                    end of mystery(1)
                "We did it again with n = 2"
                end of mystery(2)
            "We did it again with n = 3"
            end of mystery(3)
        "We did it again with n = 4"
        end of mystery(4)
    "We did it again with n = 5"
    end of mystery(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good way of thinking about recursive programs: when you read program's code, pretend that you know what the program does, even though you don't know it yet. In your situation, this would look like this:

- **If `n == 0`, print fixed message** - that's the `no more recursive calls!` string
- **If `n != 0`, print `n` followed by printing whatever the program prints for `n-1`, followed by printing `n` again** - in other words, there's a "frame" of two messages around whatever the program prints for `n-1`

Here is how this would look:

```
mystery called with n = <something>
... whatever the program prints in between...
We did it again with n = <something>
```

The first printout happens *before* entering the recursive part of the call; the last printout happens *after* returning from the recursive part. Note that `<something>` is the same at the top and at the bottom, because the value of `n` is stored on each stack frame, and gets set to the previous value as the recursion unwinds.

With this picture in place, it is easy to see that you keep adding nested "frames" until you hit `n==0`, at which point you print the message in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The first five times through the mystery method, **the method does not stop at the recursive call**. It continues on, to output "we did it again." But I suppose since mystery is blocking, the method is only allowed to finish up once the last recursive call is returned. So upon hitting n = 0 the first five calls continue on to their original conclusion, printing "We did it again with n = ..."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a run through of what this recursive method does:

```
mystery(5): {
|   println( "mystery called with n = 5" );
|
|   n != 0:
|       skip return
|
|   mystery(n - 1) is mystery(4)
|
|   call mystery(4): {
|   |   println( "mystery called with n = 4" );
|   |
|   |   n != 0:
|   |       skip return
|   |
|   |   mystery(n - 1) is mystery(3)
|   |
|   |   call mystery(3): {
|   |   |   println( "mystery called with n = 3" );
|   |   |
|   |   |   n != 0:
|   |   |       skip return
|   |   |
|   |   |   mystery(n - 1) is mystery(2);
|   |   |
|   |   |   call mystery(2): {
|   |   |   |   println( "mystery called with n = 2" );
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   n != 0:
|   |   |   |       skip return
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   mystery(n - 1) is mystery(1);
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   call mystery(1): {
|   |   |   |   |   println( "mystery called with n = 1" );
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   n != 0:
|   |   |   |   |       skip return
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   mystery(n - 1) is mystery(0);
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   call mystery(0): {
|   |   |   |   |   |   println( "mystery called with n = 0" );
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   n == 0:
|   |   |   |   |   |       return from mystery(0)
|   |   |   |   |   }
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   back inside mystery(1), continue executing where we left off
|   |   |   |   |   println("We did it again with n = 1")
|   |   |   |   |   method ends; return to caller
|   |   |   |   }
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   back inside mystery(2), continue executing where we left off
|   |   |   |   println("We did it again with n = 2")
|   |   |   |   method ends; return to caller
|   |   |   }
|   |   |
|   |   |   back inside mystery(3), continue executing where we left off
|   |   |   println("We did it again with n = 3")
|   |   |   method ends; return to caller
|   |   }
|   |
|   |   back inside mystery(4), continue executing where we left off
|   |   println("We did it again with n = 4")
|   |   method ends; return to caller
|   }
|
|   back inside mystery(5), continue executing where we left off
|   println("We did it again with n = 5")
|   method ends; program ends
}
```